# Install .htaccess files in VPS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I can`t use in my VPS RewriteRule and forwarding in .htaccess files. I have install apache2, but I can`t usage this files. Why? How install .htaccess in VPS?

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and allow overrides in the apache configuration for the site?

Comment: Regretfully, this is not really programming related but professional server management related.

Comment: As I said, you can. You need to enable mod_rewrite and setup your apache configuration to allow for overrides (IE: reading of .htaccess)

Comment: But how do I do that?

Comment: Once again, this is a question unrelated to programming and is better suited for serverfault.

Comment: Firstly, you need to investigate what web server software you are using. If this is a Linux Apache MySQL PHP (LAMP) install, then you can investigate enabling Mod_Rewrite for Apache. A google search will reveal an easy command: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. Of course if you are not using Apache, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mod_rewrite is enabled, then in your Apache configuration, make sure `AllowOverride all` is set instead of `AllowOverride none`, but be sure you understand the security implications first.  If both of those things are already covered, make sure your .htaccess files include `RewriteEngine on` before you try to use the other Rewrite directives.